# Image/File hosting storage best practices and standards

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, web-hosting, document-management

We are building an image and file hosting website and we will save these files on our servers, so I want to know if there are any best practices or standards I need to read and follow to make our website scalable and easy to extend in the future.

Is there a book or articles or videos talking about this subject, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my experience to deal with large data.

- its always best to opt for Cloud, check for "[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)" ([Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/console/)) or Windows Azure.
- features like "CDN" ([cloud front](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)) is a big plus.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not a simple question that can be answered without knowing

- how many files are expected ?
- how many users/files accesses per hour/day/minute ?
- your usage scenarios with this files (downloading? streaming? how many concurrent files downloaded at once?
- are you stuck in one particular OS (windows) and filesystem (NTFS), or is there freedom in this ?

My personal note : Building own image/file hosting is not a trivial task, i strongly recommend you to hire somebody with experience from this area.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that if possible, you look at a 3rd party solution that provides an api. you'll then get the benefits of lower cost of ownership, no maintenance costs for the hardware and continual updates thrown in for free when the 3rd party adds new features to the core offering. I know this from 1st hand experience as we scoped out the options for doing this in a recent project and came to the conclusion that we'd spend 100 times more on our own solution and even then, may not get it right. We opted for a company called  Razuna who offer both a hosted and open source version of their platform. Their api is very straightfwd and can be consumed inside your mvc app with potentially only a few days effort (depending on your use case). The beauty of this approach is that the hosted elements are actually on the nirvanix backbone and are served via their CDN - so win win.

You can get the details at:

http://www.razuna.com

and can view the api docs at:

http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/Developer+Guides

Good luck and if you need any further real-life guidence on this, feel free to come back. Oh and btw, we were also able to ask for 'paid for' features to be added to the core offering at pretty much standard market day rates.